# Яндекс Share Api (блок "Поделиться") для React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пытаюсь прикрутить блок "Поделиться" в мое React приложение. Написал такой компонент:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class YandexShare extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.Ya.share2('ya', {
      theme: { services: 'vkontakte,facebook,gplus,linkedin' },
      content: { url: 'example.com' }
    });
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="ya" />;
  }
}

export default YandexShare;
```

добавил скрипт в страницу

```
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

и ничего не работает, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Это что за такой удивительный тег `<div className="ya" />`?

Answer (score 1):

Измени

```
<div className="ya" />
```

на

```
<div id="ya" />
```